# Application of Jordan's lemma to $\frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1}$ (or find alternatives)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $C_R$ denote the upper-half circle with large radius $R$, and let $0<a<1$. I want to show that
$$I= \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{C_R} \frac{e^{az}}{e^z+1} dz=0$$
using Jordan's lemma (or if this does not work, otherwise).

Putting $I=\int_{C_R} f(z)dz=\int_{C_R}e^{i\alpha z}g(z)dz$, we have
$$I\leq \frac{\pi}{\alpha}\max_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} |g(Re^{i\theta})|=\frac{\pi}{\alpha}\max_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} \left| e^{-i\alpha Re^{i\theta}} \frac{
e^{aRe^{i\theta}}}{e^{Re^{i\theta}}+1} \right|$$

However, this diverges if $Re^{i\theta}=(2n-1)i\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, which is possible for $\theta=\pi/2$ and $R=(2n-1)\pi$.

I suspect there must be another way to show that $I=0$, but how do you show this?

Comment: Do you want to show that $I$ tends to $0$ as $R \to +\infty$? $I = 0$ is not true. $R$ has to approach to infinity in a discrete way avoiding the poles of the integrand.

Comment: @Gary I have edited the question accordingly to include that limit.